# Apache .htaccess not being read

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to figure this out. I'm using Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have mod_headers enabled. In my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file, I have the following default Directory statements:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I'm trying to override the default apache2.conf config by using VirtualHosts for my actual website directory in /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin blahblah@123456.so
        ServerName 999.999.999.999
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domains/website1
        <Directory /var/www/html/domains/website1>
                        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order Deny,Allow
                        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The website works just fine but whenever I try to enable SEO friendly URLs, I get a 404 error stating the page does not exist. Here's the .htaccess file located in /var/www/html/domains/website1/ (It's a standard Wordpress .htaccess file):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. I figured it out as I was filling out the Tags section of the form and the tag mod-rewrite popped up as one of the suggestions. I needed mod_rewrite enabled! Durp. Well, thanks to the stackoverflow web developers for building that feature into the site :)